# Code-first MVC 4 using Entity Framework and SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, authentication, connection-string, code-first

> This question is **not** about SQL Server "3xpr355" (the obfuscation
>   in quotes is by design; it should prevent future searches from hitting
>   dead-ends, as mine have done).

---

I am using code-first and Entity Framework to develop an MVC 4 application. The SQL Server, IIS, and Visual Studio are all running on the same machine.

I was originally using SQL Server "3xpr355" but the requirement to put it on an exposed-to-the-Internet-via-ISS machine made hooking it up to a full-featured SQL Server necessary. I have the application set up to drop and re-create the database whenever the models change:

```
public class XyzDBContext : DbContext
{
    public XyzDBContext()
        : base("XyzDBContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<XyzDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<XyzDBContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<XyzModel> XyzModels{ get; set; }
}
```

Here are my connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add 
  name="DefaultConnection" 
  connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Xyz-20150131102119;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 <add
  name="XyzDBContext"
  connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=XyzDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**Expectations:**

- Execution of the portions of the application that use XyzDBContext should cause the database "XyzDatabase" to be created (if necessary).
- Execution of the portions of the application that use the Membership Provider should cause the database "aspnet-Xyz-20150131102119" to be created (if necessary).

**Actual Results:**

- Exception is thrown: System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException "An
  error occurred while getting provider information from the database.
  This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection
  string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the
  connection string is correct."
- Inner Exception:
  System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException "The provider did not
  return a ProviderManifestToken string."
- Inner Exception:
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException "Login failed for user
  'DOMAIN\SERVER$'."

**Measures:**

- I have tried using SQL Server Management Studio to add a login for the "DOMAIN\SERVER$" user, but the login always fails.
- I have researched and tried many permutations of the connection strings, all but a few of the examples I have found were for use with SQL Server "3xpr355".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is multifaceted:

**Create an Application Pool**

In IIS Manager, visit the "Application Pools" node and select the "Add Application Pool..." Action:
[image: Creating the application pool]

Select the new Application Pool and select the "Advanced Settings..." Action, then select the "..." button (on the "Identity" field):
[image: Changing the application pool identity]

**Set the Application Pool identity to "LocalSystem"**

[image: Setting the identity to LocalSystem]

**Grant Permission**

In SQL Server Management Studio (when connected to the database service), visit the "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" node under "Logins" and bring up the "Properties" view, then select the "Server Roles" page, and grant all of the privileges by selecting the check-boxes:
[image: Granting all privileges]

In IIS Manager, Right-click on your site and select "Manage Application/Advanced Settings..." and Set the "Application Pool" property value to "CodeFirstMVC".

**Run the Application**

Run the application and visit the areas that would require a new database to be created; you should now see a new database on your SQL Server instance.

Comment: That was my answer ! Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Well if you map each connection string (database) to it's own DbContext the you could reach your expectations but you still have to work with two contexts (which is painful).
Your third actual result is due to IIS that can't connect to the database. You have to go to IIS manager and change the identity of the application pool under which your application runs (You can change it to LocalSystem)
Finally, try this if you have already the databases created:

```
public class DefaultConnectionContext : DbContext, IDisposable
    {
        public DefaultConnectionContext()
            : base("name=DefaultConnection")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DefaultConnectionContext>(null);
        }

        // Some dbsets

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

public class XyzDBContext : DbContext, IDisposable
    {
        public XyzDBContext()
            : base("name=XyzDBContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<XyzDBContext>(null);
        }

        // Some dbsets

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Hope That helps

Comment: Thanks for the Application Pool suggestion; it did not work out-of-the-box but it took my efforts in a new direction. Please expunge the un-obfuscated mention of "3xpr355" from your answer and I will up-vote it as helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help, I had the same issue some weeks ago and changing the application pool's identity solved it, here's how to do it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28v=ws.10%29.aspx